# Shortening a frequently run command

Tags: command-line

I want to shorten

```
sudo http_proxy="http://proxy:port" apt-get ______
```

to

```
sudo rep apt-get ________
```

Is this possible to implement in Ubuntu?

#### EDIT:

So I added

```
alias rapt-get="http_proxy="10.1.1.26:8080" apt-get"
```

to my `~/.bash_aliases`. I have other working aliases in this file.

If I type rapt-get in the terminal, I get:

```
apt 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10 for amd64 compiled on Apr 20 2012 10:19:39
Usage: apt-get [options] command
       apt-get [options] install|remove pkg1 [pkg2 ...]
       apt-get [options] source pkg1 [pkg2 ...]
```

`apt-get` is a simple command line interface for downloading and
installing packages. The most frequently used commands are update
and install.

#### Commands:

```
update - Retrieve new lists of packages
upgrade - Perform an upgrade
install - Install new packages (pkg is libc6 not libc6.deb)
remove - Remove packages
autoremove - Remove automatically all unused packages
purge - Remove packages and config files
source - Download source archives
build-dep - Configure build-dependencies for source packages
dist-upgrade - Distribution upgrade, see apt-get(8)
dselect-upgrade - Follow dselect selections
clean - Erase downloaded archive files
autoclean - Erase old downloaded archive files
check - Verify that there are no broken dependencies
changelog - Download and display the changelog for the given package
download - Download the binary package into the current directory
```

#### Options:

```
-h  This help text.
-q  Loggable output - no progress indicator
-qq No output except for errors
-d  Download only - do NOT install or unpack archives
-s  No-act. Perform ordering simulation
-y  Assume Yes to all queries and do not prompt
-f  Attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place
-m  Attempt to continue if archives are unlocatable
-u  Show a list of upgraded packages as well
-b  Build the source package after fetching it
-V  Show verbose version numbers
-c=? Read this configuration file
-o=? Set an arbitrary configuration option, eg -o dir::cache=/tmp
See the apt-get(8), sources.list(5) and apt.conf(5) manual pages for more information and options.
This APT has Super Cow Powers. Seems to be working. But if i type `sudo rapt-get update`, I get 

sudo: rapt-get: command not found
```

(Sorry for the formatting issues, I'm on through mobile and can't see the formatting bar)

Comment: One of the problems may be the use of `"` in the `alias`. To use a `"` in your command, prepend it with a "\" so that it looks like this `alias rapt-get="http_proxy=\"10.1.1.26:8080\" apt-get"`

Answer (score 1):

You can also make an sh script that reads input, inserts it into the command and runs it. I would upload a file like that for you, but I do not have access to my computer.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your `/etc/sudoers` settings as well. For starters, as pointed out, the *alias* won't even be available within the `sudo` context. However, you could adjust your alias to say:

```
alias rapt-get='http_proxy="10.1.1.26:8080" sudo apt-get'
```

i.e. include the variable that you set for this invocation. If you wanted `sudo` to take this over from the user's context you'll have to edit `/etc/sudoers` in order to add the variable name to the `env_check` or  `env_keep` setting. Quoting `man sudoers`:

> By default, the `env_reset` option is enabled.  This causes commands to
>   be executed with a minimal environment containing `TERM`, `PATH`,
>   `HOME`, `MAIL`, `SHELL`, `LOGNAME`, `USER` and `USERNAME` in addition
>   to variables from the invoking process permitted by the `env_check`
>   and `env_keep` options. This is effectively a whitelist for
>   environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

`~/.bashrc` adds aliases for you, and only you

`sudo` runs as root. Even though you may have administrator access, your user is not root.

So, add your alias to `~root/.bashrc` (generally this is `/root/.bashrc`).

If you'd like to add this alias for all users, add it to `/etc/profile`